# проблема с проксированием через nginx docker

Tags: nginx, docker

В докере установлен nginx-proxy, конфигурация ниже
Запросы проксируются на основной nginx
В основном nginx при настройке прав доступа через модуль ngx_http_access_module не пускает с разрешенных ip
location / {

```
allow 95.205.111.13;
allow 95.205.111.14;
deny  all;
```

}

В error.log nginx ошибка 
[error] 29#29: *63 access forbidden by rule, client: 172.22.0.2,
Т.е. получается с прокси идет на нжинкс внутренний адрес, хотя в access.log nginx поступает верный ip
"GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 83665 "http://site.ru/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.117 Safari/537.36" "95.205.111.13"
вот docker-compose nginx-proxy
version: '3.0'

services:

proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    # image: jwilder/nginx-proxy:alpine
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
    networks:
      - proxy

networks:
  proxy:
    driver: bridge

Как его наставить на путь истинный, что бы он определял верный ip?

Comment: Покажите конфиг как вы проксируете запросы.

Comment: стандартно в docker-compose.yml снаружи установлен nginx-proxy 
version: '3.0'
services:


  proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    # image: jwilder/nginx-proxy:alpine
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
    networks:
      - proxy

  whoami:
    image: jwilder/whoami
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=whoami.local


networks:   
  proxy:
    driver: bridge

Comment: и далее уже на сервере основном (nginx)  environment:
            - VIRTUAL_HOST=site1.ru, site2.ru

Answer (score 1):

Ну все верно.
У теб второй nginx не пускает первый.

```
access forbidden by rule, client: 172.22.0.2
```

в конфе первого в цепочке nginx добавь proxy_pass директивы для проброса реального IP а не свего.

```
proxy_set_header HOST $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_set_Header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```